# Is it possible to specify metadata on object display when DisplayForModel doesn't apply?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a situation where I want to show an object that isn't attached to a model, but I'd like to specify metadata for it so that the templating system displays it **as if** it were a model property with specified metadata.  Something like:

```
@Html.DisplayObject(obj, metadata)   <--pseudocode
```

That is, I have a free object `obj` and I know how I want it to be displayed (usual metadata stuff like DisplayName, FormatString, UIHint, etc.), but this object isn't attached to a model.

How can I hook into MVC's default templating logic in this situation?

(The reason the object isn't attached to a model, by the way, is that it's loaded dynamically at runtime, so there's no compile time place to add the property and decorate it with the metadata attributes.  So I may really be asking about the right way to handle this situation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a brilliant answer by any means, but in the end I just manually implemented the UI that I needed, factored into useful partial views and helper methods, and it really wasn't that hard.  I also have complete control, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option here is to implement your custom metadata provider. I never did it myself but this [article on the topic](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/why-you-dont-need-modelmetadataattributes.html) looked useful and detailed.

Comment: I spent a few painful hours on this and couldn't get it to work enough to accomplish my goal.  I was able to serve up metadata, but I couldn't get MVC to use it as intended, and in the end it was faster to just roll my own.